# Are there any test data generator tools which can be used with selenium/Nunit?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, selenium

I was wondering if there was anything that provides test data for injecting into Nunit tests?

I'm sure I came across something recently that does this but I couldn't find it again.
Basically the idea is that I could use selenium and Nunit to create new customers within the system automatically.

So I could have selenium type in customer names generated from test generator (the < DataGenerator > is just an imaginary class):
e.g.

```
dim sFirstName as string = < DataGenerator >.GetRandomFirstName()
dim sLastName as string = < DataGenerator >.GetRandomLastName()
selenium.type("firstname_field",sFirstName)
selenium.type("lastname_field",sLastName )
```

I've already seen SQLDataGenerator from Redgate which has a cmd line wrapper class, but I was wondering if there was anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)?

It looks for input and output parameters and can work with many unit testing frameworks including NUnit.

Depending on how your methods are organized, this could work to generate test data for your methods.

Take a look at the video [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Peli/Getting-started-with-Pex-in-Visual-Studio-2008/) to see a demo.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look. I was also looking at xeger which is a regular expression data generator. Basically it provides a random string given a RegEx, but it is only available in Java and hasn't been ported to .NET unfortunately (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at http://www.fakenamegenerator.com. This site has an API you can call or you can download a CSV file of up to 50,000 records that you can then access from your script. They provide quite a bit of basic demographic information including interrelations between the data (so no 6 foot tall, 180 lb 5 year olds, for example).